# Why is request object not the same between a "native" view and a ModelViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building an API with Django Rest Framework (DRF) and enabled the authentication/registration through social apps.

For authenticating users via their social accounts I use Django rest-framework Social Oauth2 and it works like a charm. To be sure my user is logged in I created a very simple view in the views.py of my app:

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("is_anonymous: %s" % request.user.is_anonymous)
```

The result in the browser is the following (it means that the user is logged in):

> is_anonymous: False

Now as I am building an API with DRF I may need to retrieve some data of the current user (from request.user) in one of my viewsets but in the following code, the result is not what I expected:

```
class HelloViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Hello.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HelloSerializer

    # This is just a random ViewSet, what is
    # important is the custom view below

    @action(detail=False)
    def test(self, request):
        return Response(request.user.is_anonymous)
```

Here the result shows that the user not logged in:

> True

So the first view shows that request.user.is_anonymous = False and the second shows that request.user.is_anonymous = True. Both views are in the same file views.py in the same app.

What do I miss here? We are not supposed to get the user instance in an API REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As neverwalkaloner mentioned in the  in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173364/why-is-request-object-not-the-same-between-a-native-view-and-a-modelviewset#comment87367050_50173735), the problem was that I didn't pass any access_token in the header via `Authorization: Bearer <token>`, so of course the server wasn't able to identify the "logged" user that was making the request. Using curl (or Postman) I could add this token for checking purpose and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is because your first view is pure Django and it's not using DRF's `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`. To enable it, you can add `@api_view` decorator:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view()
def index(request):
    return Response("is_anonymous: %s" % request.user.is_anonymous)
```

Also you should update `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` to enable OAuth, like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Comment: As you guessed it seems that the authentication system used was different between the two views, now both views send True for "request.user.is_anonymous". But then it still means that I can't access the data of the user that logged in if the view is outside the "pure django view" since he's considered anonymous (note: I used facebook to log in). Is there a way to make the login action use the default authentication classes given above? (I don't have any clue if that's the problem, I just feel like my login doesn't use the right authentication classes)

Comment: @SugarMouse did you provide `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header?

Comment: I didn't, is it mandatory? How should I get this token? Last time I retrieved the token of a user it was by using /auth/token route but I had to add username and password data as parameters, but a "social user" doesn't have a password

Comment: @SugarMouse without this token DRF not able to authenticate user. You need to convert  social token to access token. Check django rest social auth documentation to clarify hot to do it.

Comment: I was trying to use OAuth 2.0 without really knowing how it worked, obviously sooner or later my lack of understanding was going to be a problem. This token passed in the Authorization was indeed what I was looking for!